# How to find string element in array regardless of upper or lower case

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, case-sensitive

I want to display alert if `myString` is present in `myArray`:

```
var myString = "A"
var myArray = [A]
if contains(self.arrayGroup, self.txtGroupName.text) {
   let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Sorry :("
        alert.message = "Duplicate Name"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alert.show()
}
```

But if the `myString` is in opposite case, the alert is not showing :(

```
var myStr = "As"
var myArr = [AS]
if contains(self.arrayGroup, self.txtGroupName.text) {
   let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Sorry :("
        alert.message = "Duplicate Name"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alert.show()
}
```

How can I find `myString` in `myArray` ignoring case?

Comment: please provide proper code, that one is surely not working while your intentions are quite clear. the println statement never prints nil in your cases, in one case it prints something, in the other case it is not even reached. Dont over-simplify your code.

Comment: sorry, updated my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing what you are looking for is something like the following:

```
let search = "b"
let arrayToSearch = ["A", "B", "C"]
let searchResult = arrayToSearch.filter() { $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(search) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame }
if searchResult.count != 0 {
    print("'\(search)' matched to '\(searchResult[0])'")
} else {
    print("'\(search)'not found")
}
```

which will output

> 'b' matched to 'B'